# ruby singleton configuration not obtain the configured value after exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Ruby on Rails singleton class and I wanted the ability to configure this class while application is initialized.

I followed this articles:

http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/ruby-gem-configuration-patterns/ https://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block

Changes that I made:

I did not create a gem file, I'm loading my singleton class while the application is loaded by adding the class file path to `config.autoload_paths`

I added a file inside the "initializers" directory look like this.

```
MYClass.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = APP_CONFIG['key']
  config.api_secret_key = APP_CONFIG['secret_key']
  config.base_url ='https://api.domain.com'
  config.api_version = 'v2'
end
```

my class look like this:

```
module MYClass
  class << self

    attr_writer :configuration

   #do something just simulate a call to the configuration class
   def get_api_config
      configuration.api_key
   end


  end 


  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end

  def self.configure
    yield(configuration)
  end


  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :api_key, :api_secret_key, :base_url, :api_version
    def initialize
      @api_key = nil
      @api_secret_key = nil
      @base_url = 'https://api.domain.com'
      @api_version = 'v2'
    end
  end
end
```

Everything is working fine until I have an exception.

After that, my configuration object allocated again in the next call to MyClass.get_api_config and `api_key,api_secret_key are equals to nil`

Comment: Could you be more explicit by what you mean by 'have an exception'?. Is the underlying cause rails' development mode code reloading ?

Comment: i don't really understand your question. Inside my class i'm calling RestClient::Resource.post and if post returned with exception 404 after catch this exception the configuration parameters are gone.

Comment: If the problem doesn't happen after setting config.cache_classes = true & restarting then it's the development mode code reloading that is tripping you up

Comment: @FrederickCheung i will try but .. how come it is not happening to all other gems that use this pattern ??

Comment: Gems aren't reloaded but code in your app is

Answer (score 0):

How about making it a true singleton using `extend self`. Generally a config does not need to be instantiated because it is meant to be a free floating singleton available throughout the application. Try this and see how it works for you

```
module MyClass
  class << self
     def get_api_config
       Configuration.api_key
     end
     def configure
       block_given? ? yield(Configuration) : Configuration
     end
     def configuration
       Configuration
     end
  end


  module Configuration
    extend self
    attr_accessor :api_key, :api_secret_key, :base_url, :api_version

    def base_url
      @base_url ||= 'https://api.domain.com'
    end
    def api_version
      @api_version ||= 'v2'
    end
    def config(&block)
      instance_eval(&block)
    end
  end
end
```

I added all the methods you used although I don't think some of them are needed. I also set your defaults for you with out the need to initialize a class for `Configuration` because it does not appear you would need more than 1 instance.

Now you can do things like

```
MyClass.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = "Test KEY"
  config.api_secret_key = "Secret"
end
MyClass::Configuration.api_secret_key 
#=> "Secret"
MyClass::Configuration.base_url
#=> "https://api.domain.com"
MyClass.configuration.api_version
#=> 'v2'
MyClass.get_api_config
#=> "Test KEY"
MyClass::Configuration.singleton_methods
#=>[:api_key, :api_key=, :api_secret_key, :api_secret_key=, 
    :base_url, :base_url=, :api_version, :api_version=, :config]
```

In this case all references to MyClass::Configuration will always return the same regardless of where they are called in the application.

Comment: This is not working each time there is an exception the Configuration object contains only `@base_url and @api_version` variables and arguments

Comment: @user730250 if the exception is not handled then yes of course because the whole application crashed and all context will be lost. Otherwise the variables set will remain in tact throughout the running process. I use this kind of configuration file all the time.